# comparing AES vs RSA with openssl speed?

Tags: openssl

Doing openssl speed on AES and RSA:

AES

```
                     16      64          256         1024         8192
128 - key size  117450.07   125740.18   127472.13   127666.43   126015.65
192 - key size  102463.74   107677.17   110151.66   111042.35   110820.17
256 - key size  87653.64    94099.24    96100.69    94219.3      94235.4
```

RSA

```
                    sign/s    verify/s
 512 bits           1258       21887.7
 1024 bits          205.3      4726.2
 2048 bits          30.6       1072.6
 4096 bits           4.5        284.7
```

What can I say about each of their performance? How can I compare them?

Comment: You're comparing oranges to apples. What is the original problem?

Comment: i wanna say what these data are saying about them? And what does it tell about their performance?

Comment: It tells nothing, you're comparing incomparable. What's the original problem you're solving?

Answer (score 0):

`RSA` is not a replacement of `AES`, nor the other way. AES is a symmetrical algorithm and RSA is any asymmetric one. RSA involves exponential operations whereas AES uses substitution, rotation, addition and other relatively simpler operations. This comparison is meaningless as both have different purpose.

As a practice, RSA or other asymmetric algorithm is used for key-exchange (of other symmetric algorithm) or signature generation and verification.

What you can do is to compare AWS with other symmetric algorithms like IDEA, 3DES and RSA with other asymmetric algorithm like ECC, DSS.